# Can “was not ᴠᴇʀʙing” and “will not ᴠᴇʀʙ” ever be exact equivalents in reported speech?

Tags: meaning, sequence-of-tenses, indirect-speech, future-in-past, deontic-vs-epistemic

Do English speakers understand this sentence:

1. I told him I **wasn’t playing** soccer anymore.

Exactly as they would this sentence:

2. I told him I **will not play soccer** anymore.

If so, why would they consider those two to be exact equivalents?

Comment: Using the (past, as reported speech) continuous shows a practice that occurred up until 'quite recently' as relating to the time of the statement. This choice shows less abruptness (and connotes a lingering fondness) than the more clinical 'I told him I didn’t play soccer anymore'.

Comment: What I said to him was "I don't play soccer any more". Which means I won't play it in the future, either. What I reported was "I told him that I didn't play soccer any more". I talked to him in the present tense, but I reported what I said in the past.

Comment: They don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is reported speech, where we backshift tenses. Backshifting happens when a verb tense is shifted back to a past form in reported speech.

What was said by John: "I am hungry." In reported speech, we see "John said that he was hungry."

In your example "I told him I wasn’t playing soccer anymore", what was actually said was "I'm not playing soccer any more".

[Backshifting in reported speech](https://busyteacher.org/14657-backshifting-reported-speech-how-to-esl.html)

Answer (score 13):

The short answer is that no, they do not mean the same thing.

The first with an inflection of the progressive construction *be playing* is a simple statement of the evidentiary future, but the second with an inflection of *will play* is a statement of a future that the speaker insists must come to pass.

## Probabilities *vs* Demands

When someone says:

1. I will not play soccer anymore.

This sentence has two possible meanings, both quite different from the
other. It can mean either of:

2. I **refuse** to play soccer anymore. (*deontic modality*)
3. I **am not going** to play soccer anymore. (*epistemic modality*)

When (1) is equivalent to (2), the modal verb
*will* is here acting in what we call its [***deontic
modality***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) because
the speaker is asserting how the world ***ought to be***, what they are
**insisting** that it ***must become***.  This mode of *will not* is the
same as *do not want to* or indeed even *refuse to* because it involves
a volition (a “wanting”, so to speak) or a permission or a demand,
Basically, this is the sense of the verb *will* that actually means *want*
or *insist* or *demand*.  They are saying that while it is not that way
now, they are insisting that it **must** become that way in the future.

In sharp contrast, when (1) is equivalent to (3), that same
modal verb *will* is now acting in what we call its [***epistemic
modality***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) because
the speaker is simply stating how they believe the world is likely to
be or become.  They are not attempting to impose their desire on the
world. They’re only presenting the evidence of how it is or how it is
going to be.

## Embedded Speech: *Backshifting and Frontshifting*

When you embed the statement given by (1) in embedded speech such as
you do with *tell X that Y*, you can do so with respect to the past
(*told, did tell, was telling*), the present (*tells, does tell, am telling, have told*),
or the future (*will tell, going to tell, will be telling*) in the new
surrounding clause.

Your choice for the surrounding verb’s expression of time “leaks through” to
“color” (meaning change) the time of the embedded clause’s verb as well.
The constriction *will not play* uses the verb *will* in its present tense,
**by which I mean its *morphological inflection* with respect to time.**

That morphological tense can be retained under indirect speech **only** when
the outer verb *tell* is **also** in the present tense, as it is in:

4. I **have told** him that I ***will*** not play soccer anymore.

Notice how both clauses use present-tense inflections, *have* and *will*.

However, when the outer verb *tell* is instead in its past tense *told*, you
must **also** use the past tense of *will* to the past tense, which is *would*:

5. I **told** him that I ***would* not play** soccer anymore.

This is what we call ***backshifting***, something that happens
in embedded clauses because of the tense of the surrounding matrix clause.

Now, English has no morphological inflection of tense to show future
times, just various sorts of periphrastic expressions such as the
present-tense applications of modal *will* or of *be going to*. So using
one of these expressional periphrases for *tell* to express future times
while still using the present tense does not change the tense of the
verb *play* in the clause which *tell* is embedding:

6. I **will tell** him that I **will not play** soccer anymore.

### Making Progress

For added emphasis, it is possible to use progressive *‑ɪɴɢ*
inflections in the embedded clause. When you do this, you always leave
their own verbs in the present tense as dictated by the embedding verb’s
present (or arguably better put, its **nonpast**) tense:

7. I **will tell** him that I **will not be playing** soccer anymore.
8. I **will tell** him that I **am not playing** soccer anymore.
9. I **will tell** him that I **am not going to play** soccer anymore.
10. I **will tell** him that I **am not going to be playing** soccer anymore.

You can think of this as backshifting’s opposite, a sort of
“frontshifting” so to speak.  But it is by no means mandatory. For
the vast majority of occasions, the simpler version given by (6) is
perfectly adequate. It’s also more common, probably because when possible,
we prefer simpler and lighter verbal constructions over those that are
heavier and more complicated.

Of course, all those periphrastic forms involving *‑ɪɴɢ* progressives
can be used just as easily when a matrix verb is in the past tense, not
just when it is in the nonpast tense. But when you do that, because of
backshifting you must also switch all the tenses in the embedded clause
so that they match the tense of the other clause:

11. I **told** him that I ***would* not be playing** soccer anymore.
12. I **told** him that I ***was* not playing** soccer anymore.
13. I **told** him that I ***was* not going to play** soccer anymore.
14. I **told** him that I ***was* not going to be playing** soccer anymore.

There all the present-tense uses of *will* and *am* have all been backshifted to each
of those two present-tense verbs’ respective past-tense forms, namely
*would* and *was*.

## Modalities Again

Just as the bi-modal (1) can have both the deontic reading of (2) and the
epistemic reading of (3), every time you embed (1) into another clause
as we’ve done for all the rest of these examples (4–14), you again
have both possible modalities potentially active here.  It all depends on the speaker’s perspective and intended meaning.

#### Deontic Embeddings

Those embedded examples that use either tense inflection of *will*
within the embedded clause are more likely to be in the **deontic mode
of *insistence***.  These are examples (4), (5), (6), (7), and (11) —
because they all use an inflection of the modal *will* in the embedded interior clause. The tense of the exterior clause governs that of the interior one.

#### Epistemic Embeddings

In contrast, the embedded examples that use some inflection of *be
going to* within their embedded clause are more likely to be in the
**epistemic mode of *probability***.  Those are examples (8), (9), (10),
(12), (13), and (14) — because they all use a suitably inflected form of the progressive *be going to*
instead of the modal *will* within their embedded clause. As before, the tense of the exterior clause governs that of the interior one.